# Webpack dev server removes require variable

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, webpack-dev-server

When I create a bundle using webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 on the entry it erases the require variable prompting the error: `Can't find variable require`.

As soon as I remove the webpack entry, the bundle works again.

This happens irrelevant if the file is served regularly opening the file from a html, or served by the WebapckDevServer.

Any reason as to why this would occur? Thank in advance for any help.

Client Config:

```
{
  entry: {
    client: [
      'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
      'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
      './client'
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: join(rootDirectory, 'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: ''
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    // new DefinePlugin({
    //   'process.env': {
    //     'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
    //     'PORT': 8080,
    //     'SERVER': false,
    //     'CLIENT': true
    //   }
    // }),
    new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
      template: './index.tmp.html',
      filename: 'index.html',
      chunks: ['client']
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ]
}
```

Comment: Be sure that you added `webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin` in `plugins` section. And could you provide full error message?

Comment: Yeah, it is included in the plugins. The entire error that throws the browser is `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require`. Specifically this line `module.exports = require("url");`

Comment: Sorry, cannot find out the reason without config. `module.exports = require("url");` is this line located in your code?

Comment: No, it is a line included when adding webpack-dev-server in the entry array.

Comment: Try to specify libraryTarget: `output { ..., libraryTarget = "commonjs2"  }`